# How to format bootstrap 4 button to display parts of text at different spots of button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering how to edit the css of a bootstrap 4 button to display the text in various different positions for a project I have in school.

Here is an image of the button

[image]

I'd like it to be where Puppies and Cost are in the same spot but x27 is enlarged to the size of the button and aligned to the right side of the button.

Does anyone know of how one could do this?

This is the current code I have that is related to this question

```js
document.getElementById("BP").innerHTML = " Puppies  x" + puppyarray.length + "<br>" + "Cost: " + puppiescost;
```

```css
.dogbut:first-line {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.dogbut {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button id="BP" onclick="BP()" type="button" class="btn btn-light w-100 dogbut" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Cost: 10 | +.3 BPS">
     Puppies
<br>
     Cost: 10 Borks
</button>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Towkir I wasnt able to upload a picture as I need two more rep and i didn't notice my css was messed up

Comment: The element is it a button ?!

Comment: @Conan I just added the HTML to my button, that should hopefully clear things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could accomplish this task. I've demo'd an example below assuming you know the height and width of this button. There are likely more clever alternatives that are more dynamic.

Basically, use flex to control the position of the elements and wrap your data values in spans to give yourself control via CSS. Using pseudo classes is a real pain for stuff like this imho.

```css
button.my-btn{
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height:80px;
}

.my-left{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.number{
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="my-btn btn btn-primary">
 <div class="my-left">
   <span class="puppies">Puppies</span>
   <span class="cost">Cost: 1331</span>
  </div>
  <div class="my-right">
    <span class="number">x27</span>
  </div>
</button>
```

EDIT: It would probably be important to include the JS eh

Here's how I would modify your js that modifies your DOM

```
document.getElementById("BP").innerHTML = `<div class="my-left">
   <span class="puppies">Puppies</span>
   <span class="cost">Cost: ${puppiescost}</span>
  </div>
  <div class="my-right">
    <span class="number">x${puppyarray.length}</span>
  </div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your button is like this.

```html
<button id="BP"><button>
```

You should maybe do something this way (not tested).

```
var BP = document.getElementById("BP");
var span = BP.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
span.textContent = "Puppies x" + puppyarray.length;
var small = BP.appendChild(document.createElement("small"));
small.textContent = "Cost : " + puppiescost;
```

Then your CSS.

```
#BP span {
    display : block;
    font-size : 13px;
}

#BP small {
    font-size: 9px;
}
```